# Web page integrated code editor

Tags: java, c#, ide, editor

I'm writing a tool for screening interview candidates at my company. The idea is to send them a URL to a website where they'll receive a set of programming problems. Candidates have to solve the problems in an integrated code editor on the website, after which they submit their solutions and I can evaluate them.

Important features are:

- support several languages such as Java and C# mandatory, but C/C++,
  Python, JavaScript are also preferred
- compile and run the code on the website
- some kind of console support for displaying the compilation errors
- some kind of test environment that validates their own tests such as the Test Explorer in Visual Studio
- it would also be nice to have a project structure, so that candidates can add test files -> helping us verify what tests they write alongside the code

We would also like to find an editor that is open source and easy to integrate, because there is no budget to spend on this tool and the time constraint for us is pretty rough.

Do you have any recommendations that fit my description?

Comment: I've never used this product before and I'm not associated with them in any way, but it seems to be pretty close to what you are looking for. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/codingground.htm

Comment: So what if we want to customize it? As far as I see this is not open source.